# Finite cover of a nonsingular variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm doing some work on locally principal divisors, and am fairly new to Algebraic Geometry. In Shafarevich III.1.2 it is asserted that givenany divisor D, for any point x in a nonsingular variety one can find a neighbourhood in which D is principal.

It is then stated that from amongst all of these neighbourhoods one can choose a finite cover of X. I'm moderately confused as to why this is immediately obvious as I cannot find any resresults saying X is compact or similar.

Comment: A variety is a Noetherian scheme......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all varieties are *quasi-compact*, meaning any open cover has a finite subcover. (*Compact* usually includes the Hausdorff condition, which is the reason for this slightly awkward terminology in the case of varieties.)

This result is surely in Hartshorne Chapter II, although at a level of generality beyond what you want. The proof in your case isn't hard, though — the essential point is that a finitely generated $k$-algebra $A$ is Noetherian, so $\operatorname{Spec} A$ satisfies the descending chain condition for closed sets.

Comment: Thanks! I do have Hartshorne, but havent covered sheaves or schemes yet.